ALSA to play 5.1 on on microphone and line in jacks
Steps redirect surround channels to microphone and line in jacks
> aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
...

.
> aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Front output / input
...
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC662 rev1 Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, Philips FTV
    HDMI Audio Output
usbstream:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH
    USB Stream Output

.
> cat /proc/asound/card*/codec#* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC662 rev1
Codec: Intel CougarPoint HDMI

.
> sudo hdajackretask
Green jack (Line Out): Front Left/Right
Blue jack (Line In): Rear Left/Right
Pink jack (Mic): Subwoofer/Center

.
> amixer
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 54384 [83%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 54384 [83%] [on]
  Rear Left: Playback 54384 [83%] [on]
  Rear Right: Playback 54384 [83%] [on]
  Front Center: Playback 54384 [83%] [on]
  Woofer: Playback 54384 [83%] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined
...

.
> cat .asoundrc
cat .asoundrc
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type hw
        card 0
        device 0
        channels 6
    }
}

.
> speaker-test -c 6
speaker-test 1.2.10
Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 6 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
ALSA lib pcm_params.c:2226:(snd1_pcm_hw_refine_slave) Slave PCM not usable
Broken configuration for playback: no configurations available: Invalid argument
Setting of hwparams failed: Invalid argument

Then comment # channels 6
> speaker-test -c 6
speaker-test 1.2.10
Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 6 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 64 to 1048576
Period size range from 32 to 524288
Using max buffer size 1048576
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 262144
was set buffer_size = 1048576
 0 - Front Left
 1 - Front Right
 2 - Unused
 3 - Unused
 4 - Unused
 5 - Unused

At this point i have no ideas how to enable to play on mic and line in jacks?
PS
XH61V motherboard; Audio Realtek® ALC 662 6-channel High-Definition Audio; Three analog audio connectors (3.5mm) at the Back-Panel:

Front Line out (head phone)
Rear Surround line-out (shared with microphone input)
Center line-out (shared with Line in)

